# XTerm*faceName in .Xresources are not reflected

Tags: xorg, xterm, fontconfig, x-resources

I've tried customizing zsh's prompt with change the font but during it, xterm become not to reflect the `XTerm*faceName` in`~/.Xresources`.

Here is my dot files:

> ~/.xinitrc

```
#!/bin/sh

# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
#
# global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit(startx)

# invoke global X session script
. /etc/X11/Xsession

xrdb -merge $HOME/.Xresources
exec awesome
```

> ~/.Xresources

```
XTerm*termName: xterm-256color
XTerm*locale:   true
XTerm*selectToClipboard:    true
XTerm*faceName: Shure Tech Mono Nerd Font Complete
XTerm*faceSize: 12

!TomorrowNightEighties
#define t_background        #2d2d2d
#define t_current_line      #393939
#define t_selection         #515151
#define t_foreground        #cccccc
#define t_comment           #999999
#define t_red               #f2777a
#define t_orange            #f99157
#define t_yellow            #ffcc66
#define t_green             #99cc99
#define t_aqua              #66cccc
#define t_blue              #6699cc
#define t_purple            #cc99cc


*.foreground:   t_foreground
*.background:   t_background
*.cursorColor:  #aeafad

! Black / Grey
*.color0:       #000000
*.color8:       #666666

! Red / Bright Red
*.color1:       t_red
*.color9:       #FF3334

! Green + Bright Green
*.color2:       t_green
*.color10:      #9ec400

! Yellow (Orange) + Bright Yellow (Yellow)
*.color3:       t_orange
*.color11:      t_yellow

! Blue + Bright Blue
*.color4:       t_blue
*.color12:      t_blue

! Magenta (Purple) + Bright Magenta
*.color5:       t_purple
*.color13:      #b777e0

! Cyan (Aqua) + Bright Cyan
*.color6:       t_aqua
*.color14:      #54ced6

! Light Grey (Selection) + White (Current Line)
*.color7:       t_selection
*.color15:      t_current_line
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image: The screenshot: left is the true font I want but actually show as right]

Although I'd already restart vm (= restart X), the font was still old one although other elements like theme were reflected properly.

Other information:

Ubuntu 18.04 on vmware

awesomewm as a window manager

zsh as shell

Comment: Looking at the manpage, `faceName` requires FreeType support compiled into `xterm`. No idea if your version of `xterm` has that. Does `font` etc. work (with the usual bitmap fonts)?

Comment: I tried writing `"XTerm.font = Shure Tech.." ` and restarting, but the result is the same. Also, I tried `xterm -fa "Shure Tech..."` and `xterm -fn "Shure Tech..."` and both are same, old font was shown.

Comment: If "Shure Tech ..." isn't a bitmap font, this won't work. Run `xfontsel` or `xlsfonts`, pick a standard font that's installed, e.g. `-misc-fixed-medium-*`, try `*.font: misc-fixed-medium-*` or `xterm -fn 'misc-fixed-medium-*'` (but use a proper size). This won't tell you if `faceName` works, if will tell you only whether you can set fonts in principle. Next step is to use FreeType tools to list your installed fonts, and try one of those with `faceName`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant font *family* name is **`ShureTechMono NF`**, which you can find using `fc-list`.  Here is a screenshot.
[image: xterm using ShureTechMono NF]

The `fc-list` manual page suggests this command (**`:`** matches everything, the **`family`** parameter shows the face-family used by xterm):

```
fc-list : family
```

The xterm manual page entry for [**`faceName`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName) also gives an example using `fc-list`:

```
fc-list :scalable=true:spacing=mono: family
```

Comment: This, `fc-list : family` works for me. 

The problem occured by using `fc-list : file | grep "Shure"` = `Shure Tech Mono...` but `fc-list : family | grep "Shure"`  suggests `ShureTechMono...` (=no space between these three).
After I follow it, the font get changed (I need Nerd Font in order to use plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the -fn parameter, and entering the font name using Pango notation e.g. ShureTechMono\ Nerd\ Font\ Regular:px=11

I've done it this way, with a different font, trial-and-error style, before I made the final entry in .Xresources. In this example, I would not use "Complete" but "Regular" as shown explicitly in the pic.